# constants for CIFilter names

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-image

are there constant strings for names of build in filters(`CIColorControls`, `CIBloom`, etc.) in Mac OS X?

There are constant strings like `kCIInputEVKey`, which you can use to avoid string literals like `@"inputEV"`, but i can't find something similar for names of filters.

thx in advance!
Yevgeniy.

Answer (score 3):

It's hidden away, but there is a list of names of filters, and what they do:

[Core Image Filter Keys - Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIBoxBlur)

Answer (score 0):

As you’ve probably found out already, there aren’t.

While I see that filters can be provided at runtime, so in order to get the *full* picture you have to query the list of available filters at runtime, I can only guess why there isn’t a canonical set of filters that are guaranteed to exist — after all, that’s what introducing such constants boils down to.

Most (if not all) filters that were introduced in 10.4 are still around, so it’s not *too unsafe* a bet to rely on them sticking around. That said, you should probably always account for a failed lookup…